# WPF TabItem color on mouse enter and mouse leave

Tags: c#, wpf

In my style, I'm trying to set tabitem's color for mouse enter, mouse leave and selected events.

It's working partially, because the mouse enter and mouse leave events are fired even for the selected tab.

I would like to ignore these events when the tab is active. Is this possible?

This image demonstrates the current situation.

[image: menuitem style]

Here's my style

```
   <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Name="MyTab">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="35" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="105" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#f2f2f2"/>
            <!--Template-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate  TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Grid Name="Panel" Background="#424f5a" TextBlock.Foreground="#e8e8e8">
                            <Border Name="Border">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- Selected state-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#383838" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fbfbfb"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!-- Mouse enter state -->
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard >
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#5e6972" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Panel"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <EventTrigger.ExitActions>

                                </EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <!-- Mouse leave -->
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#424f5a" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Panel"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Look at `MultiTrigger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MultiTrigger because the TabItem's situation contains multiple properties combined. I did it like below and it works. You can develop it according to your wishes.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Panel"  Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#5e6972" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Panel" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#424f5a" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Panel"  Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#5e6972" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Panel" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#383838" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#383838"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

**My solution**: (see the notes below)

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Name="MyTab">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="35" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="105" />
                <!-- 3 -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#424f5a" />
    <!--Template-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                            <!-- 2 -->
                <Grid Name="Panel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" TextBlock.Foreground="#e8e8e8">
                    <Border Name="Border">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- Selected state-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <!-- 4 -->
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#383838" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fbfbfb"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- 1 -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard >
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#5e6972" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <!-- Mouse leave -->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#424f5a" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Explantion:** (please refer in my solution, that I added a comment in every place that is relevant to each explanation note)

1. first of all, I have put the `MouseEnter` / `MouseLeave` trigger events in the Style's Triggers (you will understand why, later)
2. I have made the `Grid`'s `BackGround` be TemplateBinding (Templated to the `Style`'s `BackGround`. This is needed If you want that the `Style`'s Trigger events will affect the `ControlTemplate`'s `Background` (in your case, the `Grid`'s `BackGround`).
3. Than we must specify the `Style`'s `Background` in order to create this Binding.
4. If your are sharp-eyed, you have noticed that I really hasn't changed anything in your `IsSelected` Trigger. But, and this is improtant you to know in the future, if I will remove the `TargetName="Panel"` from the `Setter` your will occur again (Check It!). The problem occures because of 2 reasons (that are connected to each other):
   The first, is that when we omitting the `TargetName` we actualy telling the setter to change the `Style`'s `Background` Property and not the `Grid`'s `Background` Property. the second reason is that `Style.Triggers` has a higher precedence than `ControlTemplate.Triggers` (read [Precedence documantation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
   that is why the `MouseLeave` Trigger will overrite the behavior of the `IsSelected` Trigger.

**To Summerize**, I am not sure that it is the only/best solution to this problem, maybe there is other best practice for this situation (I assume because it is a popular situation), but this is a very simple one, specially if you undertand all the mechanism behind.